# Python: how to write script that behaves differently in different environments

Tags: python

I'm writing a Python script and I'd like it to behave differently from my CLI than in Production. Here's how I have it currently:

```
testing = False # True

def run_test():
    if testing == True:
        print message
    else:
        alert_department(message)
```

but I don't like my core functions littered with `if/else` statements.

What better patterns should I use?

Comment: In this *particular* case, you could implement the logic in the `alert_department` function, so that you only require a single `if` statement rather than one every time you wish to call `alert_department`.  But maybe that doens't apply to all your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This particular use looks like you want `logging` with different logger configurations based on the environment. Then you can just happily

```
log = logging.getLogger('some_scope')

# ...
log.warning('Something warning-worthy occurred')
```

and your configuration determines whether it's printed to the console or whether a custom "alert department" handler is called.

In general, though, I'd recommend against having your script behave (very) differently in dev, testing and production as that makes debugging difficult.